# Storage disk url with s3 giving me the wrong s3 url

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-s3

Storage disk url  with s3 giving me the wrong s3 url

I am using Laravel's Filesystem to store items on s3 and I am getting the wrong URL.

```
request->file('company_logo')->store('library');
```

working good

and when extracet url s3 giving me the wrong s3 url

```
Storage::disk()->url($path_company_logo);
```

reselt

This URL

```
http://alumni-club-files.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/library/DyawVxh2XI82qV9b91d2sZHuwRVeUEIu8Vp8PRu2.png
```

should be

```
http://alumni-club-files.s3.amazonaws.com/library/DyawVxh2XI82qV9b91d2sZHuwRVeUEIu8Vp8PRu2.png
```

config/filesystem.php

```
        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],
```

.env

```
S3_KEY=MYKEY
S3_SECRET=mySecr3tmySecr3tmySecr3tmySecr3t
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=alumni-club-files
AWS_URL=http://alumni-club-files.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

I tryed

```
S3_KEY=MYKEY
S3_SECRET=mySecr3tmySecr3tmySecr3tmySecr3t
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=alumni-club-files
AWS_URL=http://alumni-club-files.s3.amazonaws.com
```

and

```
S3_KEY=MYKEY
S3_SECRET=mySecr3tmySecr3tmySecr3tmySecr3t
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=
AWS_BUCKET=alumni-club-files
AWS_URL=http://alumni-club-files.s3.amazonaws.com
```

the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem

file .env

use

```
AWS_URL=http://alumni-club-files.s3.amazonaws.com
```

insted of

```
AWS_URL=http://alumni-club-files.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

close  server and rerun it

```
php artisan serve
```

it's working